# Create Facebook/Google login on website

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I want people to be able to login to my website with their Google and Facebook accounts. I have already done some research about Facebook.

[This tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/) for JavaScript was quite useful. The only thing bugging me at the moment is the application id in the source code:

```
FB.init({
    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

If the id is public, wouldn't this enable anybody that would view the page source the use the application?

I have never done this before, my idea is to get the id of the facebook user which will be a reference to a user profile in my website. I plan on creating a table `facebook_has_user` in which I will store the connection between a `user_profile` and his facebook. I plan on doing something similar for Google. Is this a good idea? I know I don't have a concrete question, but I would like someone that has done this before to tell me how they have done it.

Comment: Don't facebook/google require you to attach a domain to the app id, so people can't extract it and use it on their own site?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your application id will be visibile while using JavaScript. But no, it doesn't make it vulnerable, because you can view any app id. For instance, SongPop id is `323595464361460`, as you can see in https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/323595464361460!

Answer (score 0):

> If the id is public, wouldn't this enable anybody that would view the page source the use the application?

No. Anything secure on the server end requires your secret key, which should never be made public in source code. Additionally, things like authentication are limited to the domain in your Facebook application's settings.